# Rails with simple_form: add new table row with link_to_add

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, formtastic, fields-for, cocoon-gem

I'm having problems adding a new table row  by clicking the link_to_add function link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it took me some search and try&error to find out here is my solution. The key to it was using the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) by nathanvda (instead of [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) by ryanb) that allows to define a jquery selector (called `data-association-insertion-node`) on where to insert the new fieldset. In my example I'm using HAML and Twitter Bootstrap code, but you can easily replace it with your own favorites.

**`/app/views/users/_form.html.haml`:**

```
= simple_form_for @user, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f|
  = render "shared/error_messages", :target => @user
  .row-fluid
    .span12
      .fieldset
        = f.input :username, :label => "Username:", :placeholder => "Username"

        %table.table
          %thead
            %tr
              %th
                %i.icon-calendar
                Date
              %th
                %i.icon-pencil
                Description
              %th
                %i.icon-cog
                Action
          %tbody#user_events
            = f.simple_fields_for :user_events do |event|
              = render "user_event_fields", :f => event

        = link_to_add_association f, :user_events, :"data-association-insertion-node" => "tbody#user_events", :"data-association-insertion-method" => "append", :partial => "user_event_fields", :class => "btn" do
          %i.icon-plus
          Add new event

        %p.help-block
          %strong Please note:
          Events are only removed after confirming the changes with
          %span.label
            %i.icon-ok
            Update settings!

        = f.button :submit, :class => "btn" do
          %i.icon-ok
          Update settings!
```

**`/app/views/users/_user_event_fields.html.haml`:**

```
%tr.nested-fields
  %td= f.input_field :date, :as => :date_month_year, :class => "tooltip-bottom input-small", :rel => "tooltip", :title => "Date of event", :disabled => params[:action] == "show"
  %td= f.input_field :description, :placeholder => "Description", :class => "input-large tooltip-bottom", :rel => "tooltip", :title => "Description of event<br/>Use <strong>Markdown</strong> to format your text.", :disabled => params[:action] == "show"
  %td= f.input_field :label, :placeholder => "Label", :class => "input-medium tooltip-bottom", :rel => "tooltip", :title => "Label of event", :disabled => params[:action] == "show"
  %td= f.input_field :label_class, :collection => [["Green", "label-success"], ["Yellow", "label-warning"], ["Red", "label-important"], ["Blue", "label-info"], ["Black", "label-inverse"]], :include_blank => "Grey", :class => "input-small tooltip-bottom", :rel => "tooltip", :title => "Label color of event", :disabled => params[:action] == "show"
  %td
    = link_to_remove_association f, :class => "btn" do
      %i.icon-remove
```

Please note that the `.nested-fields` class on the  tag is essential for the remove link to work.